# java.io.FilePermission when reading from "user.dir"

Tags: java, accesscontrolexception

I am getting following **error** when reading the text file.

> Test - Exception in thread "Thread-0"
>   **java.security.AccessControlException:    access denied ("java.io.FilePermission"
>   "C:CUR_SDKPkbZ17INTWDPsolWDP5_NI_PD24Towary.txt" "read")**
>       at zad2.Czytaj.run(Czytaj.java:25)

```
String fname = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Towary.txt";
try (BufferedReader scan = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname)))
```

The excercise was to read from the eclipse workspace directory a **.txt** file.

Comment: Are you sure the eclipse workspace directory is the same as "user.dir"? Are you sure your user is allowed to access that directory? What happens when you paste the contents of `fname` into Windows Explorer?

Comment: Did you modify the policy permission somehow?
http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/security.html

Comment: This programs runs on my teacher computer so I have no clue about permissions. However I can only image if the _fname_ is accessing correct path with .txt file than there is possibility to read it. My biggest concern is according to exercise I should access the file in eclipse workspace however _"user.dir"_ gives me path to exercise folder so I may be one forder ahead of the correct .txt. Just guessing.

Comment: @IgorNieradka First of all, make sure that when you print `fname`, it should be same as the path of the file you want to access. Later, try accessing that file using explorer, to check if you have the permissions or not.

Comment: Lets just put it this way, how I can access someones else eclipse workspace folder cause _("user.dir")+"/file.name"_ just does not work for me.